# how do I use natural log in numpy logspace

Tags: python, numpy

I can get evenly ln-spaced values with `np.exp(np.linspace(start=np.log(0.1), stop=np.log(100), num=20))`

[image]

But I'd rather use np.logspace. How do I use a natural base?

Using `np.logspace(start=0.1, stop=100, num=20, base=10)` does not give the desired result from above:

[image]

but `np.logspace(start=0.1, stop=100, num=20, base="ln")` and various other tries throw a TypeError on base

Comment: `np.logspace` is certainly not the equivalent of `np.exp(np.linspace(...))`.  It's essentially the opposite, right?

Comment: Doesn't `np.logspace(start=np.log(0.1),stop=np.log(100),num=20,base=np.e)` produce the same numbers?  It looks like it to me.

Comment: `np.logspace` is written in Python.  You can see its code via the docs.  It starts with `np.linspace`., and applies `np.power(base, ...)`.  Default base is 10.

Comment: Take a look at [`numpy.geomspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html).